# Why does my labels, input fields etc greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I was working on this project and it was fine. Today morning when i opened my project i see this. Everything is greyed out. I don't see any of them on my View Controller. Also the view controller is kind of greyed out.
[image]

Interestingly if i try to run my app it works fine. Please help me. Let me know if you want to know any specific about anything. Its a almost completed app and am very freaked out right now!

[Using: IOS8,Swift, Xcode 6 Beta 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use size classes?
Try to switch to wAny/hAny (bottom of the IB window) and see if your controls reappear.

Comment: holy shi** it WORKED! You are a life saver!